# Как сделать адаптивные блоки по вертикали

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, bootstrap

Есть блоки у меня они:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотелось бы сделать подобие:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть ли какой-то способ это сделать я использую **Bootstrap**.

Comment: Вам нужен вот этот скрипт. По ссылке есть сам файл, примеры и прочее - [http://masonry.desandro.com/](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Comment: Наверное, сначала лучше разобраться с flexbox, который лежит в основе работы masonry. Пример аля pinterest [тут](https://codepen.io/michellebarker/pen/zvxpoG)

Comment: @Mr.Brightside, где ты увидел, что он лежит в основе работы? По-моему, все элементы масонри используют абсолютное позиционирование относительно контейнера, который указывается в инициализации и настройке скрипта. Ведется расчет засчет оффсетов позиций на странице и строится сетка на основе этих данных. У скрипта много логики, а не простой флексбокс.

Answer (score 4):

Вероятно, придётся воспользоваться padding'ом вместо margin'а из-за проблемы с #7, но примерно так:

```css
div {
  margin: 0 0 1em;
  background: silver;
  counter-increment: i;
  
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  -moz-column-break-inside:avoid;
  -moz-page-break-inside:avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid-column;
}

body {
  -moz-column-count: 4;
  column-count: 4;
  counter-reset: i 0;
}

div:before {
  content: "#" counter(i) " - " attr(style);
}
```

```html
<div style="height:10em"></div>
<div style="height:1em"></div>
<div style="height:4em"></div>
<div style="height:16em"></div>
<div style="height:2em"></div>
<div style="height:5em"></div>
<div style="height:7em"></div>
<div style="height:12em"></div>
<div style="height:11em"></div>
<div style="height:3em"></div>
```

Comment: Page-break-inside это же для печати , для чего в том случае ?

Comment: @Geyan, для тех, кто не поддерживает `break-inside` вполне срабатывает `page-break-inside`.

Answer (score 1):

Есть ещё вариант со скриптом:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.flexboxes').masonry({
    itemSelector: 'div' // обращаемся к пунктам
  });
});
```

```css
.flexboxes {
  display: flex;
}

.flexboxes > div {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://masonry.desandro.com/masonry.pkgd.js"></script>

<div class="flexboxes">
  <div style="height:10em">0</div>
  <div style="height:1em">1</div>
  <div style="height:4em">2</div>
  <div style="height:16em">3</div>
  <div style="height:2em">4</div>
  <div style="height:5em">5</div>
  <div style="height:7em">6</div>
  <div style="height:12em">7</div>
  <div style="height:11em">8</div>
  <div style="height:3em">9</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Что-то напоминает...

Answer (score 0):

1) Каждая колонка будет отдельным циклом;
2) Использовать абсолютное позиционирование, к примеру, как на Pinterest сделано.

Comment: Колонка будет циклом? Что?

Answer (score 0):

Вариант 1 - Pinterest: в скрипте получить размеры изображений, затем с помощью абсолютного позиционирования установить положение каждой карточки
[`link`](https://codepen.io/robotmarvinus/pen/BaNKxXQ)

Вариант 2 - Yandex collections [columns]: создать колонки, а затем вставлять в них предварительно созданные изображения 
[`link`](https://codepen.io/robotmarvinus/pen/poJbBdb)

Дополнительно:
Вариант 3 - Vkontakte [строки]: создаем строки, предварительно определяем размеры изображений, масштабируем изображения до ширины строки и выравниваем высоты
[`link`](https://codepen.io/robotmarvinus/pen/GRJqPaK)