# Выравнивание блоков по вертикали в несколько колонок в родителе с неизвестной высотой

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Нужно выровнять блоки подобным образом:

```css
.flexboxes {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 200px; /* Без указания этой высоты */
  flex-direction: column;
}
.flexboxes > div {width:200px;background-color:red;margin:3px;}
.block0 {height: 60px;}
.block1 {height: 80px;}
.block2 {height: 70px;}
.block3 {height: 90px;}
.block4 {height: 80px;}
.block5 {height: 100px;}
```

```html
<div class="flexboxes">
  <div class="block0"></div>
  <div class="block1"></div>
  <div class="block2"></div>
  <div class="block3"></div>
  <div class="block4"></div>
  <div class="block5"></div>
</div>
```

Как добиться такого же эффекта, но без указания высоты у `.flexboxes`. Возможно ли это сделать на чистом CSS?

**Интересует решение без JS. Также решение должно быть с неизвестной высотой. Под неизвестной высотой имеется ввиду неизвестная высота не только родителя, но и дочерних блоков. Не стоит голосовать за закрытие вопроса только потому, что вы не можете дать объективно верный ответ.**

Comment: а есть дизайн или прототип, а то не понятно что вообще нужно

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich а код я для чего предоставил?

Comment: Могу вам сказать что код работает

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich может еще и вопрос прочитаете?

Comment: @Vadizar Зря огрызаетесь. Мне тоже непонятна вопроса.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov а может немного подумать нужно? Кажется разжевал как нельзя лучше.

Comment: @Vadizar, P.S. оскорбителен у вас. Используйте скрипт. По другому не выйдет

Comment: @Yuri, да просто бесит, что 3 голоса за закрытие, когда вопрос предельно ясно описал. Пока и так сделал скриптом. Но как по мне, так не очень красиво. Возможно есть какое решение и на CSS и я делаю что-то неверно.

Comment: @Vadizar, если бы было решение, то не нужно было бы эти скрипты создавать :)

Comment: @Yuri ну сприптик я сам этот написал) А вообще плагины масонри, писались еще до flexbox.

Comment: @Vadizar, на счёт того, что вопрос был и так ясен - согласен, но за огрызки могут дать бан или понаставить минусы :) Я сейчас попробую подумать над этим вопросом. Хотя где-то я отвечал на похожий вопрос

Comment: @Vadizar, держи решения: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/593531/Как-сделать-адаптивные-блоки-по-вертикали/

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать адаптивные блоки по вертикали](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/593531/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8)

Comment: @Vadizar, тут всё понятно, вопрос закрыт как дубликат :) Не та причина просто указана

Comment: @vp_arth вопрос был в другом.

Comment: @Yuri вопрос о другом. Я не просил копировать решение с другого вопроса. Вопрос вовсе о другом.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***1) Вариант с колонок:***

```css
div {
  margin: 0 0 1em;
  background: silver;
  counter-increment: i;
  
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  -moz-column-break-inside:avoid;
  -moz-page-break-inside:avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid-column;
}

body {
  -moz-column-count: 4;
  column-count: 4;
  counter-reset: i 0;
}

div:before {
  content: "#" counter(i) " - " attr(style);
}
```

```html
<div style="height:10em"></div>
<div style="height:1em"></div>
<div style="height:4em"></div>
<div style="height:16em"></div>
<div style="height:2em"></div>
<div style="height:5em"></div>
<div style="height:7em"></div>
<div style="height:12em"></div>
<div style="height:11em"></div>
<div style="height:3em"></div>
```

<sub>[Ответ участника @Qwertiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/593650/20458)</sub>

***2) Вариант со скриптом:***

```js
$(function() {
  $('.flexboxes').masonry({
    itemSelector: 'div' // обращаемся к пунктам
  });
});
```

```css
.flexboxes {
  display: flex;
}

.flexboxes > div {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<div class="flexboxes">
  <div style="height:10em">0</div>
  <div style="height:1em">1</div>
  <div style="height:4em">2</div>
  <div style="height:16em">3</div>
  <div style="height:2em">4</div>
  <div style="height:5em">5</div>
  <div style="height:7em">6</div>
  <div style="height:12em">7</div>
  <div style="height:11em">8</div>
  <div style="height:3em">9</div>
</div>
```

<sub>[Ответ участника @Yuri](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/609830/20458)</sub>

<sup>[*Связанный вопрос*](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/593531/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8/)</sup>

Comment: это не ответ. Во-первых - я говорил, что интересует решение без JS. Во-вторых - решение с неизвестной высотой. Под неизвестной высотой имеется ввиду неизвестная высота не только родителя, но и дочерних блоков. Ненужно отмечать вопрос как дубликат, хотя это вовсе не так.

Comment: @Vadizar, а ничего что первый вариант подходит? Высота там указана, чтобы показать, что оно работает

Comment: – вы не поняли вопрос. Ожидамемое поведение ваш ответ не выполняет.