# Резиновая галерея

Tags: html, css

Имеется резиновая галерея. И пока фотографии одинаковой высоты, всё выглядит нормально, но как только какая-то фотка больше или меньше, естественно, выглядит все уже не так, как хочется.

Вопрос: как это исправить?

Задать картинкам фиксированную высоту нельзя, поскольку при изменении размера экрана рушатся их пропорции; в процентах не получается, поскольку их родительский блок `li` не имеет фиксированной высоты.

Как выкрутится в данной ситуации с помощью CSS? Или единственный выход здесь это JS?

```css
.photo_wall {
  width: 100%;
}

ul {
  line-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="photo_wall">
  <ul>
    <li><img src="../img/photo2_1.jpg" alt="photo"></li>
    <li><img src="../img/photo2_2.jpg" alt="photo"></li>
    <li><img src="../img/photo2_3.jpg" alt="photo"></li>
    <li><img src="../img/photo2_4.jpg" alt="photo"></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li><img src="../img/photo3_1.jpg" alt="photo"></li>
    <li><img src="../img/photo3_2.jpg" alt="photo"></li>
    <li><img src="../img/photo3_3.jpg" alt="photo"></li>
    <li><img src="../img/photo3_4.jpg" alt="photo"></li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: Рекомендую удалить ваш ответ и вместо этого добавить ваши мысли в вопрос. Ответы не для этого предназначены.

Comment: К сожалению, эта проблема актуальна и по сей день. Единственный нормальный выход, на мой взгляд, это JS. Но можете воспользоваться вариантами с [этого вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/636174/) или [с этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/593531/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Делаем адаптивные кирпичики [по этой статье](http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html). Я взял квадратные, но можно сделать прямоугольники с любым соотношением между шириной и высотой.
2. Количество кирпичиков в строке задаём медиа-запросами.
3. Картинки помещаем фоном и задаём [свойство `background-size`](https://webref.ru/css/background-size).

Если задать `contain`, то картинки будут видны целиком как здесь:
https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/NggQvJ

```css
.gallery-box {
  border: solid 6px transparent;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
@media (min-width:  500px) { .gallery-box { width: 50%; } }
@media (min-width:  768px) { .gallery-box { width: 33.33333333%; } }
@media (min-width:  992px) { .gallery-box { width: 25%; } }
@media (min-width: 1200px) { .gallery-box { width: 16.66666667%; } }
.gallery-box:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 100%;
}
.gallery-box__image {
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: contain;
     -moz-background-size: contain;
       -o-background-size: contain;
          background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="gallery-box"><div class="gallery-box__image" style="background-image:url(https://i.pinimg.com/564x/0e/0e/24/0e0e249eb0a4abd82c56373a3b376ccc.jpg)"></div></div>
  <div class="gallery-box"><div class="gallery-box__image" style="background-image:url(https://i.pinimg.com/564x/88/1e/c7/881ec72ce016c20153cd5022c5cf786c.jpg)"></div></div>
  <div class="gallery-box"><div class="gallery-box__image" style="background-image:url(https://i.pinimg.com/564x/6a/a7/c0/6aa7c09e41ea5a0459d2c2c2a097d9fc.jpg)"></div></div>

  <div class="gallery-box"><div class="gallery-box__image" style="background-image:url(https://i.pinimg.com/564x/0e/0e/24/0e0e249eb0a4abd82c56373a3b376ccc.jpg)"></div></div>
  <div class="gallery-box"><div class="gallery-box__image" style="background-image:url(https://i.pinimg.com/564x/88/1e/c7/881ec72ce016c20153cd5022c5cf786c.jpg)"></div></div>
  <div class="gallery-box"><div class="gallery-box__image" style="background-image:url(https://i.pinimg.com/564x/6a/a7/c0/6aa7c09e41ea5a0459d2c2c2a097d9fc.jpg)"></div></div>

  <div class="gallery-box"><div class="gallery-box__image" style="background-image:url(https://i.pinimg.com/564x/0e/0e/24/0e0e249eb0a4abd82c56373a3b376ccc.jpg)"></div></div>
  <div class="gallery-box"><div class="gallery-box__image" style="background-image:url(https://i.pinimg.com/564x/88/1e/c7/881ec72ce016c20153cd5022c5cf786c.jpg)"></div></div>
  <div class="gallery-box"><div class="gallery-box__image" style="background-image:url(https://i.pinimg.com/564x/6a/a7/c0/6aa7c09e41ea5a0459d2c2c2a097d9fc.jpg)"></div></div>

  <div class="gallery-box"><div class="gallery-box__image" style="background-image:url(https://i.pinimg.com/564x/0e/0e/24/0e0e249eb0a4abd82c56373a3b376ccc.jpg)"></div></div>
  <div class="gallery-box"><div class="gallery-box__image" style="background-image:url(https://i.pinimg.com/564x/88/1e/c7/881ec72ce016c20153cd5022c5cf786c.jpg)"></div></div>
  <div class="gallery-box"><div class="gallery-box__image" style="background-image:url(https://i.pinimg.com/564x/6a/a7/c0/6aa7c09e41ea5a0459d2c2c2a097d9fc.jpg)"></div></div>
</div>
```

А если `cover`, то заполнят собой всю доступную площадь. Получится похоже на инстаграм:
https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/Zyygab

```css
.gallery-box {
  border: solid 2px transparent;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
@media (min-width:  500px) { .gallery-box { width: 50%; } }
@media (min-width:  768px) { .gallery-box { width: 33.33333333%; } }
@media (min-width:  992px) { .gallery-box { width: 25%; } }
@media (min-width: 1200px) { .gallery-box { width: 16.66666667%; } }
.gallery-box:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 100%;
}
.gallery-box__image {
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
     -moz-background-size: cover;
       -o-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="gallery-box"><div class="gallery-box__image" style="background-image:url(https://i.pinimg.com/564x/0e/0e/24/0e0e249eb0a4abd82c56373a3b376ccc.jpg)"></div></div>
  <div class="gallery-box"><div class="gallery-box__image" style="background-image:url(https://i.pinimg.com/564x/88/1e/c7/881ec72ce016c20153cd5022c5cf786c.jpg)"></div></div>
  <div class="gallery-box"><div class="gallery-box__image" style="background-image:url(https://i.pinimg.com/564x/6a/a7/c0/6aa7c09e41ea5a0459d2c2c2a097d9fc.jpg)"></div></div>

  <div class="gallery-box"><div class="gallery-box__image" style="background-image:url(https://i.pinimg.com/564x/0e/0e/24/0e0e249eb0a4abd82c56373a3b376ccc.jpg)"></div></div>
  <div class="gallery-box"><div class="gallery-box__image" style="background-image:url(https://i.pinimg.com/564x/88/1e/c7/881ec72ce016c20153cd5022c5cf786c.jpg)"></div></div>
  <div class="gallery-box"><div class="gallery-box__image" style="background-image:url(https://i.pinimg.com/564x/6a/a7/c0/6aa7c09e41ea5a0459d2c2c2a097d9fc.jpg)"></div></div>

  <div class="gallery-box"><div class="gallery-box__image" style="background-image:url(https://i.pinimg.com/564x/0e/0e/24/0e0e249eb0a4abd82c56373a3b376ccc.jpg)"></div></div>
  <div class="gallery-box"><div class="gallery-box__image" style="background-image:url(https://i.pinimg.com/564x/88/1e/c7/881ec72ce016c20153cd5022c5cf786c.jpg)"></div></div>
  <div class="gallery-box"><div class="gallery-box__image" style="background-image:url(https://i.pinimg.com/564x/6a/a7/c0/6aa7c09e41ea5a0459d2c2c2a097d9fc.jpg)"></div></div>

  <div class="gallery-box"><div class="gallery-box__image" style="background-image:url(https://i.pinimg.com/564x/0e/0e/24/0e0e249eb0a4abd82c56373a3b376ccc.jpg)"></div></div>
  <div class="gallery-box"><div class="gallery-box__image" style="background-image:url(https://i.pinimg.com/564x/88/1e/c7/881ec72ce016c20153cd5022c5cf786c.jpg)"></div></div>
  <div class="gallery-box"><div class="gallery-box__image" style="background-image:url(https://i.pinimg.com/564x/6a/a7/c0/6aa7c09e41ea5a0459d2c2c2a097d9fc.jpg)"></div></div>
</div>
```