# Выравнивание блоков в несколько колонок с неизвестной высотой

Tags: html, css

Нужно выровнять блоки подобным образом:

```css
.flexboxes {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 200px; /* Без указания этой высоты */
  flex-direction: column;
}
.flexboxes > div {width:200px;background-color:red;margin:3px;}
.block0 {height: 60px;}
.block1 {height: 80px;}
.block2 {height: 70px;}
.block3 {height: 90px;}
.block4 {height: 80px;}
.block5 {height: 100px;}
```

```html
<div class="flexboxes">
  <div class="block0"></div>
  <div class="block1"></div>
  <div class="block2"></div>
  <div class="block3"></div>
  <div class="block4"></div>
  <div class="block5"></div>
</div>
```

Как добиться такого же эффекта, но без указания высоты у `.flexboxes` и блоков с контентом? Возможно ли это сделать на чистом CSS?

**Предложенное решение в [данном вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/593531/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8/) совершенно не интересует:**

1. Решение должно быть без JS.
2. Решение должно быть с неизвестной высотой. Под неизвестной высотой
   имеется ввиду неизвестная высота не только родителя, но и дочерних
   блоков.

Comment: Зачем ты опять это же задал?

Comment: @Yuri во-первых, кто вам разрешал общаться со мной на "ты"? Мы с вами водку не пили. Во-вторых - зачем вы голосовали за закрытие, тогда как вопрос совершенно другой?

Comment: 1) Это тот же самый вопрос. 2) Я вам в прошлом дал ответ без *CSS* 3) Нельзя задавать один и тот же вопрос два раза

Comment: @Yuri я вам объяснил, что ваш ответ не подходит.

Comment: Не хорошо два раза одно и тоже задавать, товарищ

Comment: @Yuri прочитайте пожалуйста требования.

Comment: @Vadizar, там можно не указывать высоту тем блокам. Там высота задана для того, чтобы показать, что оно работает

Comment: @AnatShir не хорошо минусовать, из-за того, что вы не можете прочитать вопрос.

Comment: @Vadizar, я не ставил минус. А вот сейчас поставил :)

Comment: @Yuri, нет высота там берется через attr

Comment: @Vadizar, уберите те высоты и посмотрите сами

Comment: @Yuri - убрал. Блоки съезжают. Отступы не ровные. Скинул бы скрин, но в комментах нельзя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.container {
  width:500px;
  border:1xp solid red;
  -webkit-columns: 300px;
    -moz-columns: 300px;
    columns: 130px 6;
    -webkit-column-gap: 40px;
    -moz-column-gap: 40px;
    column-gap: 40px;
  
}

.item {
    padding: 10px;
    background:green;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    break-inside: avoid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="item">some text some text some text some text </div>
   <div class="item"> some text some text some text some text </div>
   <div class="item"> some text some text some text </div>
   <div class="item">some text some text </div>
   <div class="item">some text some text some text </div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

что то типа такого?

Comment: Верно, именно такое поведение требуется. Однако блок не должен  разбиваться на несколько колонок, а переноситься целиком.

Comment: @Vadizar, тут-то тоже не по порядку идут блоки.

Comment: я подумал что Вам нужна колонкой сделать. У вас flex column поэтому блок идут колонкой

Answer (score 3):

Это действительно не сложно.

```css
/* ------------- Контейнер с адаптивными блоками------------- */

.masonry {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  column-gap: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  column-count: 3;
  break-inside: avoid;
}


/* Элементы в виде плиток с содержанием */

[class^="item"] {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 5px 0px;
  width: 200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.item1 {
  height: 120px;
}

.item2 {
  height: 140px;
}

.item3 {
  height: 80px;
}

.item4 {
  height: 170px;
}

.item5 {
  height: 124px;
}

.item6 {
  height: 65px;
}

.item7 {
  height: 33px;
}

.item8 {
  height: 163px;
}

.item9 {
  height: 177.77px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Контейнер с адаптиными блоками -->
<div class="masonry">
  <!-- Адаптивные блоки с содержанием -->
  <div class="item1">
  </div>
  <div class="item2">
  </div>
  <div class="item3">
  </div>
  <div class="item4">
  </div>
  <div class="item5">
  </div>
  <div class="item6">
  </div>
  <div class="item7">
  </div>
  <div class="item8">
  </div>
  <div class="item9">
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Конец контейнера с адаптивными блоками -->
```

Comment: Блоки не идут друг за другом. А если средний блок будет в разы больше по высоте соседних? Пользователю придется наблюдать пустое пространство?

Comment: @Vadizar, Сейчас идут. Я бы вообще рекомендовал не использовать флексы в таком построении, просто потому, что иначе пропуски никак не убрать. Либо с дыркой с флексами, либо использовать columns + хак с инлайн-блок элементами. Этот вариант 100% удовлетворит твоему запросу. Могу описать и его.

Comment: @Vadizar, обновил вариант.

Comment: @Vadizar, единственная проблема: блоки идут не по порядку как в ДОМ.

Comment: @Vadizar, также рекомендую скрипт Masonry. Построение сетки тогда идеальное.

Comment: Без явного указания высоты. Ваш вариант не подходит.